# How to use values outside ondataChange method? : Android Studio

Tags: android

So I want to use size of list and `allFriendsList` outside the `onDataChange` method. How can I do it?

I've shown the code below:

public class ExampleJobService extends JobService  {

```
DatabaseReference currentUserRef, friendUserRef;
FirebaseUser currentUser;
String currentUserID, friendsID;
final List<String> allFriendsLIST = new ArrayList<>();
public List<String> LISTTTT = new ArrayList<>();
int size;

private LocationManager locationManager;
private LocationListener locationListener = new MyLocationListener();
private String lat, log;
private boolean gps_enable = false;
private boolean network = false;

private NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager;

private Geocoder geocoder;
private List<Address> addresses;

private double LATITUDE;
private double LONGITUDE;

private static final String TAG = "ExampleJobService";
private boolean jobCancelled = false;


@Override
public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {

    currentUserRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    currentUserID = currentUser.getUid();
    friendUserRef = currentUserRef.child("Friends").child(currentUserID);
    locationManager = (LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);

    doBackgroundWork(params);
    return true;
}

private void doBackgroundWork(final JobParameters params){

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            SystemClock.sleep(2000);
            everythingFunction();
            jobFinished(params, false);
        }
    }).start();
}

@Override
public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Job Cancelled before complte");
    jobCancelled = true;
    return true;
}

public void dummy(String dum){
    LISTTTT.add(dum);
    int i = LISTTTT.size();
    Log.d(TAG, "dummy: " + i);
}

public void everythingFunction(){
    allFriendsLIST.clear();
    friendUserRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            final MainScreen mainScreen = new MainScreen();
            for (DataSnapshot ds: snapshot.getChildren()){
                friendsID = ds.getKey();
                allFriendsLIST.add(friendsID);

            }
            size = allFriendsLIST.size();
        }


        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
    Log.d(TAG, "SIZE: " + size);

}

class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (location != null) {
            locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
            lat = "" + location.getLatitude();
            log = "" + location.getLongitude();

            LATITUDE = Double.parseDouble(lat);
            LONGITUDE = Double.parseDouble(log);

            currentUserRef.child("Users").child(currentUserID).child("Lat").setValue(LATITUDE);
            currentUserRef.child("Users").child(currentUserID).child("Lang").setValue(LONGITUDE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }
}

public void getMyLocation() {
    try {
        gps_enable = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Toast.makeText(ExampleJobService.this, "Please Enable Location and try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    try {
        network = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Toast.makeText(ExampleJobService.this, "Please Enable Internet and try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    if (!gps_enable && !network) {
        android.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(ExampleJobService.this);
        builder.setTitle("Attention");
        builder.setMessage("Please check if internet/location are active and TRY AGAIN");
        builder.create().show();
    }

    if (gps_enable) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,0,0,locationListener);
    }

    if (network){
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,0,0,locationListener);
    }

}

public void sendNotification(String name, int D){
    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle("LOCUS")
            .setContentText(name + " is nearby! " + D + " KM away" )
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_home)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            .build();

    notificationManager.notify(1,notification);
}
```

}

Comment: initialize the size variable outside the onDataChange method, and assign value inside  onDataChange method.

Comment: Okay thank you ill try that!!

Comment: Let me know it's working or not.

Comment: Umm sorry butits not working, i declared the variable globally but still its not working, when i access in outside the value is still zero instead of 4.

Comment: show me your code plz.

Comment: i have edited and added my whole code above.

Comment: try my solution and get back to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this technique will solve your problem

Create an Interface file DataSize.java and use code given in the below

```
Interface DataSize{
    public static int size = 0;
}
```

Now use it like

```
DataSize.size = allFriendsLIST.size();
```

Now you can use this size anywhere you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
final List<String> allFriendsLIST = new ArrayList<>();
allFriendsLIST.clear();
// You can add size variable of int but not initialize
int size;

friendUserRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot ds: snapshot.getChildren()){
            friendsID = ds.getKey();
            allFriendsLIST.add(friendsID);

        }
        // initializing into interface scope        
        size = allFriendsLIST.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
    }
});
// and Here you can get actual size value
Toast.makeText(this, "$size", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```

Comment: I tried this, but then an error pops us saying "Transform 'size' into final one element array".